# Independent binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, binomial-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Let $H$ and $K$ be independent random variables. They both follow the binomial distribution of $Binomial(n,p)$.

The question is: Prove or disprove that $H+K$ and $H-K$ are independent to each other.

I know that $H+K$ is $Binomial(2n,p)$, which can be proved with the help of moment-generating functions:

$$M_{H+K}(t)=M_H(t)M_K(t)=(pe^t+1-p)^{2n}$$

However, what is the meaning of $H-K$? Is it $Binomial(0,p)$? How to solve the whole question?

Comment: $H-K$ clearly cannot have a binomial distribution because it may take negative values (what if $K>H$?). As for the meaning of $H-K$, that is quite simple - for any $\omega$, $(H-K)(\omega) = H(\omega) - K(\omega)$ (subtraction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H+K$ and $H-K$ are not independent. For 
$$\{H+K = 0, H-K = 0\} = \{H=0,K=0\}$$
and so
$$
\mathbb P(H=0,K=0) = \mathbb P(H=0)\mathbb P(K=0) = (1-p)^{2n}.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\mathbb P(H+K=0) = \mathbb P(H=0,K=0) = (1-p)^{2n}.
$$
However,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(H-K=0) &= \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb P(H=i, K = i)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \mathbb P(H=i)\mathbb P(K=i)\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \left(\binom ni p^i (1-p)^{n-i}\right)^2.
\end{align}
So clearly
$$
\mathbb P(H+K=0,H-K=0)\ne \mathbb P(H+K=0)\mathbb P(H-K=0).
$$